# aspx unable to locate code behind

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis, dll

I am able to execute my application fine using the Visual Studio IDE but when I create a release package and put it on the web server it can’t seem to find the code behind. However, if I copy the bin folder (which has the dll files) from the root directory and put it into the “root/reports” directory, everything works fine. The reports directory has all the .aspx web page files. What is causing this problem and what can I do to properly fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have `published your website`, that means your `code files were compiled into a DLL`. To work properly you have to put your `DLL's into the bin folder` on your host server.

For Details, Check this link:

[An Overview of ASP.NET Code Generation and Compilation](http://www.asp.net/hosting/tutorials/precompiling-your-website-vb)